# In STS Boot dashboard arrange projects

Tags: spring-tool-suite, spring-tools-4

In STS, boot dashboard, i have list of projects is there a way to arrange it in some order, for me configs-server, zuul, registry, oauth project needs to be started first and then rest of the projects needs to be started later.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The short answer here is: No, there doesn't exist a way to sort the projects in the boot dashboard in a particular order.

There is a way to put self-defined tags on projects and then filter the boot dashboard based on tags. While this might help a bit here, I understand that it doesn't really solve your issue.

The best would be a raise an enhancement request at:
https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues

I think this one is related (although not exactly the same):
https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/604

Comment: Thanks Martin, i have renamed my project with numbers and using it.